# Grappa (Graphviz) Tutorial?

Tags: java, graphviz

Does anyone have sample code, or a tutorial which demonstrates how to use [Grappa](http://www.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/)?  I've searched high and low and can't find anything.

Comment: For anyone else who might find this googling "grappa tutorial".. Grappa seems to be discontinued, and the documentation for it isn't sufficient to just start hacking away with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [graphiz tutorial is here](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, now if you could show me how to create a graph in Grappa I would be really appreciative!

Comment: I think if you combine the FAQ and the demo with http://www.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/grappa_faq.html the above tutorial, you could see how to begin?  Not perfect but perhaps adequate??

Comment: Yes it has some documents here : http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php